# Normalizing a random unending unknown series?

Tags: python, algorithm, math, normalization

I have an unending series with no equation, and is random, something like this,

```
   X = 1, 456, 555, 556, 557, 789 ...
```

Note that I'm getting this list as a stream, and I do not know future values, and I do not know min and max of `X`.

How do I find out the inverted normal `N(X)` for any `x in X`, such that,

`N(x) --> 0` if `x --> inf`

`N(x) --> 1` if `x --> 0`

Read that as, the greater the `x` is the closer it should be to `0`, the smaller the `x` is the closer it should be to `1`.

How can I achieve such a transformation?

I tried the following:

```
#python
def invnorm(x):
    denom = 1 + math.exp(-x)
    return 2 - (2/denom)

invnorm(200)
Out[8]: 0.0

invnorm(20)
Out[9]: 4.1223073843355e-09

invnorm(2)
Out[10]: 0.23840584404423537

invnorm(1)
Out[11]: 0.5378828427399902
```

Somehow that doesn't give a satisfactory result as my range goes on to a large number, and `200` itself gives `0` and my range will be skewed towards `0`.

Comment: Are the inputs guaranteed to be positive integers?

Comment: A very interesting question and I regret I don't have time to ponder upon it right now. Maybe try http://math.stackexchange.com/ if you don't get satisfactory answers here as this is a Mathematics problem, probably even more than computing IMHO. Good luck.

Comment: Your question is **underspecified**. `N(x)=(x>0)?1:0` satisfies your requirements, as far as I can tell.

Comment: The problem with your original function is that `e^{-x}` decreases very quickly, so that by the time you get to `x=200`, it's essentially zero.  The accepted solution fixes that problem by finding something that decreases more slowly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

OK, so you're basically looking for a continuous monotone function *N*: [0,∞) → (0,1] such that:

- lim<sub>*x* → 0</sub> *N*(*x*) = 1, and
- lim<sub>*x* → ∞</sub> *N*(*x*) = 0.

In that case, the "obvious" choice would be [*N*(*x*) = 1 / (*x* + 1)](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1+%2F+%28x+%2B+1%29), or, in Python:

```
def invnorm (x):
    return 1.0 / (x + 1)
```

Of course, there are also infinitely many other functions that satisfy these criteria, like *N*(*x*) = 1 / (*x* + 1)<sup>*a*</sup> for any positive real number *a*.

Yet another "natural" choice would be [*N*(*x*) = e<sup>−*x*</sup>](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=exp%28-x%29), or, in Python:

```
def invnorm (x):
    return math.exp(-x)
```

This can also be rescaled to *N*(*x*) = *b*<sup>−*x*</sup> for any real number *b* > 1 while still satisfying your requirements.

And of course, if we relax the monotonicity requirement (which I just assumed, even though you did not state it explicitly), even weirder functions like Abhishek Bansal's [*N*(*x*) = sin(*x*) / *x*](//www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sin%28x%29+%2F+x) will qualify.

Comment: I was thinking sin(x) / x but this beats me.

Answer (score 0):

`1 - X / M`, where `M` is the expected largest value (could be `4294967295.` for integer `X`'s).

Comment: Actually, you didn't provide enough details to allow a reasonable answer.